# To post text on Instagram

Tags: android, instagram

I am using instagram to share images and it is working fine but I want to share some image link on instagram so when clicked on that link I can see the image like on twitter .Is it possible and how to do it ?

For sharing image I used below code,

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*"); 
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,parse); 
        shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
        startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, since for now instagramm accepts only Intent.EXTRA_STREAM unfortunately. You can check same question here [Open Instagram app from another android app and send an Image with a Caption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290779/open-instagram-app-from-another-android-app-and-send-an-image-with-a-caption).