# Open Instagram app from another android app and send an Image with a Caption

Tags: android, instagram

What I basically looking for is to open Instagram app from another app and send an Image with a caption.
There is some useful documentation to do this in iOS. ([iPhone-hooks](https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/))

Do Instagram support to perform custom actions in Android like in iOS as described in [iPhone-hooks](https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/)?

Below is the current code used in my application to perform this task partially.

```
private void sendImageToIntagram(Activity activity) {
    Intent intent = activity.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
    if (intent != null) {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
        String imagePath = ImageUtil.getProcessedImage().getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(activity.getContentResolver(), imagePath, "Title", "Description")));
            // shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,  "Caption 01");
            // shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,   "Caption 02");
            // shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Caption 03");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        activity.startActivity(shareIntent);
    } else {
        // bring user to the market to download the app.

        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "com.instagram.android"));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

None of the above Title, description, Caption 01, Caption 02, Caption 03 worked.

Then I tried with,

`shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);` --> `shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);`

and,

```
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.setType("*/*");
```

too, but none of the above worked also.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer, No.

Instagram doesn't have an Android equivalent to iPhone-hooks.

They do support the `ACTION_SEND` but only take into account the `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM` on their end.

Unless something changed in the past 4 months (I doubt it) that this guy took a stub on their code, from their [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/danthemellowman/instagram-decompiled/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml#L40) you can assume, by looking in their [intent catcher](https://github.com/danthemellowman/instagram-decompiled/blob/master/smali/com/instagram/android/activity/MainTabActivity.smali#L1045) Activity that they only care for `android.intent.extra.STREAM`.

So for now, you can't send any other data than the actual image.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15002468/508479), and in particular to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663170/508479) by Chriskot, it looks that since July 2014 Instagram lets you do this.

Long story short

```
Intent instagram = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
instagram.setType("image/*");
instagram.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, [URI of photo]);
instagram.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, [Text of caption]);
instagram.setPackage(instagramPackageName);   
startActivity(instagram);
```